# file transfer from GCP VM to ec2 AWS VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, gcloud, transfer

I would like to know if there is a (preferably fast/simple) way to transfer (large) files from a GCP VM to one (or multiple) VMs hosted on AWS.

What I have tried is to run the below command on the Google VM:

```
scp -i ~/key.pub file_1 ubuntu@ec2.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

but got
 `Permissions 0644 for '/Users/anything/.ssh/key.pub' are too open. It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored. bad permissions: ignore key: /Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/key.pub Permission denied (publickey,password).`

I ran `chmod +400` on the .pub file, but still there is the following error:

```
    Load key "/home/home_folder/key.pub": invalid format                                                                                                                            
ubuntu@ec2.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Maybe I am missing something really simple here?

Tanks a bunch!

Comment: I'm not seeing your key files match up.  In your example I see "/Users/tudouya/.ssh/vm/vm_id_rsa.pub" and "/home/home_folder/key.pub".

Comment: Hi Kolban and thank you for the comment. corrected that. it was just an example, not the actual keyfile name.

Comment: What userid are you running the scp command as (run "id -a").   What are the exact permissions on the key.pub file (run "ls -l key.pub")

Comment: 1) You have the basics of SSH setup wrong. For example, normally `key.pub`, means the public key. The error `invalid format` also indicates that you have the keys set up wrong. Find a good tutorial that explains the basics of SSH and how to set up SSH authentication. 2) Your question is how to transfer large files. Use cloud storage (AWS or Google) to upload to and download from. I do not recommend machine-to-machine transfers in your case.